# conda activate the specific env in nextflow

Tags: nextflow, nextflow-tower

The version of nextflow is
N E X T F L O W ~ version 23.10.1
However, according to the official website command:

nextflow
Copy code
process foo {
conda '/path/to/an/existing/env/directory'

'''
your_command --here
'''
}
I correctly set the conda environment path in my process, but it did not activate successfully because my command:
python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)" did not display the correct version.

However, if I directly set in the script:

bash
Copy code
source /path/to/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
conda activate ${params.condaEnv1} # This variable value is my environment path
it succeeded. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you built a docker container to use with nextflow, but it's not clear.

`conda activate` in the `.bashrc` are intended for interactive shells, which is not how nextflow interacts with them. There are a few tricks in previous posts on here, but the one I like is to add the conda env to `PATH`.

From my nlrexpress dockerfile:

```
ENV PATH /opt/conda/envs/nlrexpress/bin:/usr/local/src/nlrexpress:$PATH
```

You can also use a python shebang that points to the conda version of python in some use cases and use the python script as an executable, but I think this is less flexible.

You can then test if it works by invoking something like this:

```
docker run container python3 --version
```

Which should return the conda installed python. NB, running `docker run -it` will create an interactive shell and invoke the `.bashrc` file.